# Parse String to Ast

Tags: parsing, haskell, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

I need some guidance on a few functions I made to do some parsing.

Here's my grammar (I can't change this):

```
Expr -> Int | - Expr | + Expr Expr | * Expr Expr
Int -> Digit | Digit Int
Digit -> 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

My data type (I was supposed to fill out for Min and Mult, and I think I got this correct):

```
data Ast = Num Int | Sum Ast Ast | Mult Ast Ast | Min Ast | Var String  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

So first up I made a tokenizer method, to split the string into a list of the characters:

```
tokenize :: String -> [String]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize xs @ (x : xs')
    | x `elem` t = [x] : tokenize xs'
    | isDigit x = [y | y <- takeWhile isDigit xs] : (tokenize (dropWhile isDigit xs))
    | otherwise = tokenize xs'
        where t = ['+', '-', '*']
```

This works as it should.

Next up I made the `parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast, [String])`. What this is doing is going through a list made by `tokenize :: String -> [String]` and produces the Ast recursively (I think at least)

```
parseExpr :: [String] -> (Ast,[String])
parseExpr [] = error "Error!"
parseExpr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (Num (read s),ss)
             | s == "-" = let (e,ss') = parseExpr ss in (Min e,ss')
             | s == "*" = (Mult e e',ss'')
             | s == "+" = (Sum e e',ss'') where
                          (e,ss') = parseExpr ss
                          (e',ss'') = parseExpr ss'
```

What I'm struggling with now is how I can combine these into the function `parse :: String -> Ast`. My attempt at doing this (which might be way off) is something like this. `parseExpr` produces an output of the form `(Ast, [String])`:

```
parse :: String -> Ast
parse [] = error "Empty string"
parse str = parseExpr x
  where x = tokenize str
```

My problem here is this:

Lets say I have the simple string `str = "+ 1 4"`.

```
tokenize str = ["+", "1", "4"]
```

Running this into parseExpr recursively goes through the list from tokenize and produces this output:

`(Sum (Num 1) (Num 4),[])`

It outputs the Ast and an empty list of strings.

Now the question at hand. I need to make it so that `parse "+ 1 4"` returns `(Sum (Num 1) (Num 4))` What are the ways I can do this? Do I treat the output from `parseExpr`as a list and take the Ast from the 0th index, or is this not possible? Do I have to change the way my `parseExpr` goes through the list?
Any help is greatly appreciated! BTW I cannot change any of the definitions of the functions, nor the grammar or datatype for the Ast.

Comment: Well done so far ! Next, as parseExpr returns a `(Ast,[String])` pair (or 2-tuple) object, and you just want the first component (the AST), you just need to pass the result of parseExpr to Haskell built-in function `fst`, which returns the first element of the pair, that is your AST. BTW there is also a `snd` function for the 2nd component.

Comment: Thanks!! The fact that it returned a tuple just slipped my mind. Got it to work in a matter of seconds :)

Comment: Minor note: `[y | y <- takeWhile isDigit xs]` is equivalent to `takeWhile isDigit xs`.

Comment: Make `parseExpr` (probably u should named it like `go`) as inner function and
use outer function like `parseExpr = fst . go`
Sorry I don't checked it, just written it from my mind

Comment: Also u can rewrite it via some monad like Writer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Sum (Num 1) (Num 4),[])` is a tuple and you want the first element.

You can get the first element out of a tuple with the function [`fst`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst).

```
parse :: String -> Ast
parse [] = error "Empty string"
parse str = fst $ parseExpr x
  where x = tokenize str
```